# how to open an html page using html5

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have to call other local html page from the same folder on button click. how do i call it.  given

```
$("#nextbutton").click(function(){
    //alert('heretest')
    window.location.href = 'main.html';
});
```

but not working.

Comment: You need to use the full real URL, not just the file name.

Comment: nopes still not working

Comment: Have you tried links?

Comment: Did you included **JQuery**?

Comment: Not working, so descriptive!

Comment: @gdoron, not true - please familiarize yourself with how relative paths work.

Comment: @Hogan, jQuery is needed when jQuery is being used...

Comment: @Hogan how is `$("#nextbutton").click(function()...});` pure JavaScript?

Comment: <div>
                     <input type="button" id="nextbutton" style="background-image:url(images/n1.png);"/>
          </div>

Comment: @Hogan please don't shout. Is your caps lock stuck?

Comment: @CodingDecoding Possible reasons: 1) jQuery is not included, 2) This code is executed before `#nextbutton` exists, 3) more than one element with `id="nextbutton"`, 4) File doesn't exist, 5) #nextbutton doesn't exist.

Comment: @CodingDecoding have you tried my answer? It would be nice to know I am not wasting my time by answering

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On a button click? I would suggest

HTML:

```
<input type = "button" onclick = "openpage()" value = "open page">
```

JavaScript:

```
function openpage()
{
window.location.assign("http://www.yoursite.com/main.html");
}
```

But why not just use a link?

```
<a href = "main.html">Main page</a>
```

Your question was hard to understand. I **think** this is what you want.

Comment: working finally. as other pages were overlapping on the same thats y was not able to see the output. Thanks 4 all :)

Comment: @CodingDecoding that's fine :)

Comment: -ve markings ever i got for such a small but stupid question lol